# How to change a backgroundColor to a backgroundImage with GSAP while scrolling?

Tags: reactjs, animation, gsap, scrolltrigger

I have an animation defined to the following element: parentContainerRef: gsap.to(parentContainerRef.current, {
backgroundColor: "red",
duration: 3,

```
  scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: parentContainer.current,
    start: "center top",
    markers: true,
    scrub: true,
  },
});
```

it doesn't work if I do the following: backgroundImage: "url('./assets/background.jpg')"

but it works if I do this: backgroundColor: "red",